# Rails 3 nested forms won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

My `accommodation` model:

```
class Accommodation < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_one :address
...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
...

end
```

My `address` model:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :accommodation
end
```

My `accommodation _form.html.haml` partial

```
=form_for [:panel,@accommodation], :html => {:class=>'accommodation'} do |f|
    %fieldset
    %legend
      Adres
    =f.fields_for :address do |address_f|
      =address_f.label :street, "Ulica"
      =address_f.text_field :street

    %div
```

Problem is the field for street will not show. It shows when I change :address to @accommodation.build_address but then the form is not accepted.
How to do it properly to work?

Comment: What do your `new` and `edit` actions in your controller look like?

Comment: what do you mean `the form is not accepted`?

Comment: Some error, don't remember now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:
`fields_for` needs to look like this:
`=f.fields_for :address_attributes, @accommodation.address do |address_f|`
It works perfectly now.

Comment: You know it works, but every time when you trying to edit `accommodations` it will create new `address` with `accommodations_id` null, so I am also looking for right solution

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
=f.fields_for :address, @accomodation.address.new do |address_f|
```

Comment: Any pros in comparison with my solution?